# AS3 .hitTestObject() not working with Tween function

Tags: collision-detection, actionscript-3, debugging, actionscript

(This was originally in an other senction but many told me to ask here, hopefully someone can answer this)
I am having a major problem in my new browser app.

Okay so I made game where different cubes (squares) spawn at the top of the screen and I use the Tween class to make them go down the screen and then disappear.

However I want to detect a collision when a cube hits the player (that is also a flying cube).

I tried everything, truly everything but it does not seem to work. The problematic thing is that when I remove the "Tween" function it does detect collision with the hitTestObject method but when I add the "Tween" line collision won't be detected anymore.

The code looks like this:

```
    function enemiesTimer (e:TimerEvent):void {


newEnemy = new Enemy1();
  layer2.addChild(newEnemy);
  newEnemy.x = Math.random() * 700;
  newEnemy.y = 10;
  if (enemiesThere == 0)
  {
      enemiesThere = true;
      player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collisionDetection)
  }



  var Tween1:Tween = new Tween(newEnemy, "y", null, newEnemy.y, newEnemy.y+distance, movingTime, true); }
```

The collision detection part:

```
private function collisionDetection (e:Event):void
  {


      if (player.hitTestObject(newEnemy))
      {
          trace("aaa");
      }


  }
```

*Another weird thing is that the collision detection works only in the starting point, where the squares spawn but they aren't really there anymore so I don't quite get it.

I hope someone can answer this and maybe tell me how I can code this. Thanks in advance :)

*I've tried out Tweener & TweenMax as well, the problem is always the same

Comment: I don't know how the built-in tween engine works (your observation suggests that the built-in tweens don't actually move the object, just its visual representation), you may want to get [Tweener](https://code.google.com/p/tweener/) or other 3rd party Tween library.  You could also try `hitTestPoint` though again, it will depend on what the built-in function is actually doing.

Comment: Okay thank you I will try out Tweener and see if that works out :)

Comment: Okay so I tried out Tweener, it worked but there is the exact same problem, exactly the same.

Comment: I'm not sure then. I've never tried to use tweener to handle movement in anything that wasn't pure animation.

Comment: Yes ;/ By the way I tried out TweenMax as well but it's always the same problem. It looks like all these tween libs all just move it's visual content instead of it's actual position ;/ Thanks anyways^^

Comment: Tweener packages should actually alter the .x and .y positions of the objects, so whatever's going on, I doublt its tween engine's fault.  I'm really scratching my head over this, I'm sorry. :\

Comment: Yes, it's a bit weird ;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this has nothing to do with the Tweening library you're using (as indicated in the comments) but rather with how you reference your enemy in the `collisionDetection`. Depending on how your code is structured, `newEnemy` might not be set in that scope or be set to something you're not expecting.

I suggest you try this:

```
var newEnemy:MovieClip = new Enemy1();
layer2.addChild(newEnemy);
newEnemy.x = Math.random() * 700;
newEnemy.y = 10;
newEnemy.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collisionDetection);
var Tween1:Tween = new Tween(newEnemy, "y", 
    null, newEnemy.y, newEnemy.y+distance, movingTime, true);
```

And in your `collisionDetection` method:

```
private function collisionDetection (e:Event):void
{
    // e.currentTarget is the enemey that emits the event
    if (e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(player)){
        trace("aaa");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this out. (Code was exactly the same), but it didn't work. However it didn't detect any collisions in the starting point now neither

Comment: Oh it worked, but only on the very first cube that falls down. The others don't detect collision, only the very first cube.

Comment: I think your newEnemy should be a local variable. I've updated my code

Comment: Tried it out, still only the first cube.

Comment: I think it should be `currentTarget` instead of `target` in the `collisionDetection` method. Sorry, my AS is rusty. If that doesn't work, please post your complete class somewhere and I'll have a look.

Comment: Hm, still 1 cube. Code: http://superwerer.heliohost.org/collisions.html

Comment: @werercool you still have a condition in there. I removed ` if (enemiesThere == 0)`. on purpose. That just doesn't make sense at all. Use the enemy creation code as I posted it in the answer.

Comment: Yep, tried it out didn't work either. ;/

Comment: @werercool I don't know what you did. I stripped down your code to get a simple working version and the collisions trigger just fine. Here's the code for reference: http://pastie.org/10663267

Comment: It worked!!!!! It appear I had forgotten to delete the enemiesThere in the 2nd and 3rd kinds of cubes, you were right! Thanks a lot, I can't thank you enough!